# SysTrayIcon.py menu actions with multi parameters functions

Tags: python, pywin32

Based on this popular Python PyWin32 system tray icon script:
http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html

How can I set the `menu_options` tuple and/or the relevant functions for accepting multi parameters functions for menu entries actions?

i.e.

`menu_options = (
('Complex Function', None, complex_function(a,b,c,d)),
)`

as as-it-is it only seems to accept function names with no directly-passed parameters although the function's definition must include `sysTrayIcon`.

Comment: You'll have to add that functionality in `SysTrayIcon`.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I managed to do it using [partial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial).